# Smart. Card Minidrivers test library load failed - cmck

Tags: windows, cryptography, smartcard

I am trying to use software for the certification tests of smart card Minidriver for Windows. I've established the whole infrastructure and after running

`cmmk.exe certify`

I am getting error of library loading:

```
Error: 0x7e, The specified module could not be found.
        LoadLibrary() failed for [minidriver path]
        File=ds\security\scard\test\hlk\minidriver\cmck\cardconnection.cpp Line=335
```

I have tested it as well on the other Minidriver and didn't get any error. Do you have any clue what can be wrong with my library or how could I debug it.

Comment: *The specified module could not be found.* - what unclear with this ?

Comment: The library is of-course located in the selected path.

Comment: need debug exe where this error. set bp on LoadLibrary. look which path is passed.

Comment: This log is coming from the cmok.exe I guess so I do not not have source code for that.

Comment: not need src code. binary level debugging more than enough here

Comment: The problem was that there is need to run cmck as an administrator in that case. Issue closed